# Using Com Interop in Navision

Tags: navision

I am just starting with Navision and have a very basic question. If I create a Com Object in C# where does the object need to reside? Is it local to each client or is it on the server?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what way you'll be using the object in Navision - depending on how you access it, it can either reside on the Navision DB server or it may need to be copied and registered to every client.

- What version of Navision are you using?
- Is it native-DB or SQL DB?
- What does the object do? (A rough overview is fine - is it data access, hardware manipulation, etc.)
- How is it accessed in Navision (via a report, codeunit, form, etc.)?

Comment: We are using Navision 5.0 on the clients and 4.3 on the backend. I am actually surprised it works.
It is using a SQL Server database.
I need to take a sales quote number from a Form and then query our vendors with an xml HTTPS Post and Get to see what's the current pricing and availability. A server based com object that would receive the number, lookup all of the items, prepare the xml and then send, receive and process the reply would be very easy in C#. I don't need to update the user that it has finished at least that is the current specification.

Comment: So there's no need for user feedback? The client simply posts a sales quotes and then the C# component handles the rest? How does the user know if there items are in stock, etc.?

Comment: We are going to update the Vendor Item table and then the user will be able to view the data. I also believe we are adding additional functionality to display the various branches that have inventory. This will be done in the UI of NAV.